# UI in world space drag and drop does not align with mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im doing a UI that is in World Space and i am getting strange behaviour when doing drag and drop.

https://i.imgur.com/MBZ8gNH.mp4

This is the code:

```
public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (!image.enabled) return;

    var newPosition = rectTrans.anchoredPosition + eventData.delta * canvas.scaleFactor;
    var newX = Mathf.Clamp(newPosition.x, leftSibling.x, rightSibling.x);
    var newY = Mathf.Clamp(newPosition.y, 0, height);

    rectTrans.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(newX, newY) / canvas.scaleFactor;
}
```

Comment: Afaik the [`Canvas.scaleFactor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Canvas-scaleFactor.html) only is used for Screenspace Overlay

Comment: @derHugo thsts probably right. Its always 1 however so its not doing anything strange.

Comment: Well, not sure ... have in mind that `eventData.delta` will be in screen ( =pixel) space ... you are using it as a world position since your Canvas is in `World Space`

Answer (score 0):

This one solved it for me:

```
reactTranform.anchoredPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
```